# How do I access a view from another XML File in an activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an activity named BaseActivity and I want to access a textview from another xml called dialog_progress in the BaseActivity. How do I do it

wrote the following code

```
private var tvProgressText : Textview? = null

fun showProcessDialog(text: String){
    mProgressDialog = Dialog(this)
    mProgressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_progress)
    tvProgressText = findViewById(R.id.tv_progress_bar)
    mProgressDialog.tvProgressText = text
    mProgressDialog.show()
}
```

it gives me an error saying unresolved reference for tvTextView

Answer (score 1):

give `progressDialog` reference to `findViewById` try below code

```
 private var tvProgressText : Textview? = null

fun showProcessDialog(text: String){
    mProgressDialog = Dialog(this)
    mProgressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_progress)
    tvProgressText = mProgressDialog.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_progress_bar)
    mProgressDialog.tvProgressText = text
    mProgressDialog.show()
}
```